# JPA: 2 applications needing to update one object

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an application A which has an entity Customer.

```
package stackoverflowTest.dao;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

public Customer(String name) {
this.name = name;
}


}
```

Now I have an application B which will need to update the entity.

- Do I have to do findOne(customer) and then do the update?
- How do I manage the entity class in two applications? For example, if I change the entity(add another field) in the application A, I do not want to deploy again just to be able to update the name.

I could do it the "dirty" way; meaning I have the class in both application, and do a findOne,and then do the update.

I just wanted to know if there is a better way.

thanks.

Comment: The best way to solve this is to use a common Queue(say, Kafka) and when application A makes any changes in your database, you can push this value to the Queue. From application B, you consume this changed value ie. the updated value.

Comment: Learn how to use JPA in one application. Once you know how to do that, there is no reason not to use it the exact same way on another application. I don't see how the fact that you have 2 applications is relevant to how you use JPA.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Aren't these 2 different threads on 2 different applications?

Comment: I have one main application A ( which is my big application).
The second application is just a small application listening to a queue and needs to update the name. I went for a small spring boot appliation.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya  sory I was a bit distracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, you can make a separate project to produce a jar file including your repository layer and entities. then by creating the jar file you can add it into both *applicationA* and *applicationB* **pom.xml**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This way you avoid repeating yourself across multiple projects .

In order to easily handle updating you jar file , you can also upload your recent versions on an **Artifact Repository Manager** for example: **Nexus** or **Artifactory** for easy sharing of recent jar file versions among your applications.

Comment: Artifactory or nexus not available right now. So i'll just make a copy of the entity then.

Comment: why copying? artifactory or nexus is not mandatory, these are just to facilitate the process, if you don't have them,it's fine, just as i said make a maven project with entities and their repositories, and then install it to your local repo and add the maven dependecy to applicationA and applicationB. if you don't have maven ,generated the jar file and add to lib of the projects

Comment: I went  with this solution. Nexus is not yet there. On my local machine, I generate the jar. And on my ci, I am using the jar generated by gitlab co and getting it with a get request.  Thanks

Comment: that’s great, I’m glad that it helped